# CSS - Keep image aspect ration flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a small photo gallery with some photo's.

It looks good on pc (full size), but when I resize it (for phone), it does not keep it's aspect ratio and it only streches the with.

This is what it looks like right now: https://gyazo.com/a1f605bb410865579025644b0a267adf

Also, as you can see it goes to 1 image, and at a certain point it goes back to 2 images for a split second and it stays on 1 image after. How do I fix that too?

This is my CSS:

```
    #images{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .image{
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 5px;
        min-width: 250px;
        min-height: 187.5px;
        object-fit: contain;

    }

    .image > img{
        flex: 1;
    }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="images">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="f1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="f2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="f3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="f1.jpg">
            </div>

            //it just goes on and on like this
            //it's all temporary now, I will eventualy replace 
            //this with a simple loop.

</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to using masonry?

Comment: I don't know what that is, but if it works great, Sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have very specific requirements, I suggest [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/):

> a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in
>   optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a
>   mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all
>   over the Internet.

in combination with [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) For a versatile lightweight solution.

There are many ways to implement Masonry.

The following is my personal favorite.

All my comments are inside the snippet below

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
}


/* Step 1: start with resetting some defaults */

* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Step 2: center things inside the grid and clear some space around it by setting a device based max-width and margin*/

.grid {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 95vw;
  margin: 2.5vw auto;
}


/* Step 3: how big should the gap be between grid items? remember that the total gap between two items would be double what you set here since both would have that amount set as their individual padding. Also add box-sizing:border-box to make sure the padding doesn't affect the total widh of the item */

.grid-item {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Step 4: Add media queries (subjective) to make the whole grid resposive. */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 2100px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Made possible by the great work of David DeSandro @ https://masonry.desandro.com -->

<!-- Part 1: Add the scripts -->

<!-- Step 1: Let's start by loading jQuery. jQuery is not required for masonary to function but makes things easier  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Step 2: Then load imagesloaded. imagesloaded makes sure the images are not displayed until they are fully loaded -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!-- Step 3: we load masonry -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<!-- Part 2: Create the grid -->


<!-- Step 1: Start with a the main grid wrapper-->
<div class="grid">

  <!-- Step 2: Add grid items--->

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/00/37/03/0037037f1590875493f413c1fdbd52b1--cool-beards-inspiring-photography.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/cd/90/d9/cd90d9de63fa2c8e5c5e7117e27b5c18--gritty-portrait-photography-studio-photography.jpg">
  </div>

  <!-- Step 3: repeat...--->
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9QM7ciGXRkQ/V1hsB-wNLBI/AAAAAAAAMoA/eYbSHs00PTAjrI4QAmvYAIGCUe1AuRAnwCLcB/s1600/bryan_cranston_0095.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://webneel.com/sites/default/files/images/project/best-portrait-photography-regina-pagles%20(10).jpg" />
  </div>


  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/dd/45/96/dd4596b601062eb491ea9bb8e3a78062--two-faces-baby-faces.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://www.marklobo.com.au/news/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Melbourne_Portrait_Photographer_Mark_Lobo-Cowboy.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://format-com-cld-res.cloudinary.com/image/private/s--PcYqe7Zw--/c_limit,g_center,h_65535,w_960/a_auto,fl_keep_iptc.progressive,q_95/145054-8576001-Rob-Green-by-Zuzana-Breznanikova_7725_b_w.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://www.iefimerida.gr/sites/default/files/janbanning11.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/66/bb/e7/66bbe7acc0d64da627afef440a29714b--portrait-photos-female-portrait.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/25/34/b6/2534b6c18c659546463f13b2dc62d4ce--natural-portraits-female-portraits.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8d/67/12/8d671230ced871df8428b571ed6ec192.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Part 3: the script call -->

<!-- Now that everything is loaded we create a script to trigger masonary on $grid. Note that this simply says: "if the images are fully loaded, trigger masnory on $grid. -->
<script>
  $(".grid").imagesLoaded(function() {
    $(".grid").masonry({
      itemSelector: ".grid-item"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function`

Comment: That happens if you don't have jQuery added. You need to have jQuery in your project. Masnory itself does not need jQuery and you can make it work without it. The script I used at the bottom needs jQuery. Also, make sure that jQuery is loaded before the the script at the bottom, and ideally before everything else as well.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. I already had jQuery loaded but, I loaded it in after the scrip was loaded. It works great now. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - I've added an example.

```css
#images {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  flex: 1;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/4f48e55216fe5c09963e6cac4ec2530cc08a4e36/0_0_600_600/master/600.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=add90ae66a8a0c9b35606346845539f9">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/4f48e55216fe5c09963e6cac4ec2530cc08a4e36/0_0_600_600/master/600.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=add90ae66a8a0c9b35606346845539f9">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/4f48e55216fe5c09963e6cac4ec2530cc08a4e36/0_0_600_600/master/600.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=add90ae66a8a0c9b35606346845539f9">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/4f48e55216fe5c09963e6cac4ec2530cc08a4e36/0_0_600_600/master/600.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=add90ae66a8a0c9b35606346845539f9">
  </div>

</div>
```

For keeping image aspect ratio, you can define `width:100%` and `height:auto`.
It will adjust the image to the width of the container with keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: added an example.

Comment: This is what happens:
https://gyazo.com/58174b31f1bf40222dacfd051f283366

Comment: You need to set the number of images per view with percentage.
So if you need 4 images it will be `width: 25%`

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I discover the CSS property : object-fit

She's contain multiple options :

- contain
- fill
- cover
- none
- scale-down

It's very easy, and keeps a good ratio of the image

Documentation : [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)