# Angular 2 Masonry alternative

Tags: html, angular, grid, masonry

I've tried angular2-masonry, but unfortunately I get most of the problems what won't be solved ever because the project is *dead*...

I need something which is able to automatically put order my elements like this:

[image]

As you may see I only have 2 columns (and yes, when I took the picture the masonry worked, but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly at page load, and I can't build prod with it...) and I need to stack the elements together without any gap between them. 
I only need to get something with the functionality of Masonry because my Width is fixed, only the element's high can change.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: plus the main thing that makes the pure css masonry unavalible for me: I need horizontal ordering, not vertical , so the first element should be on right top, second right to it, third: below the first one if the first one's height is equal or smaller than the second one, under the second one if the first one is heigher than the second one...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870262/8157693

Comment: thanks, looks great but I can't use the (..).imagesLoaded because I get type error which says it is not a function!

Comment: Did you add the imagesLoaded library?

Comment: with <script...> tags in the index.html yes... should I do anything else to make it work?
if I add the <script..> tags into the head section of the index.html then a new error occurs about $grid.masonry is not a function
    at ImagesLoaded

Comment: Next you need to check the load order. A- jQuery B- imagesLoaded C- Masonry and finally D- the masonry function call at the very end

Comment: It is like you've described, but I get this error: $grid.masonry is not a function
    at ImagesLoaded.<anonymous> - also it can be important that I use Angular2...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155278/discussion-between-colosh-and-i-haz-kode).